# Export list of sites from a Google Custom Search Engine

Tags: google-custom-search

I have a public [Google Custom Search Engine](http://www.google.com/cse/) with over 700 sites in its index. I can't seem to find a simple way to export the sites. What are my options?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this question is obsolete. The product has changed its name it has several changes. The current name is Programmable Search Engine. While the URL of the link is redirected to the new URL the question doesn't include enough details about the user context to know if it will stay the same. Ref. [Custom Search Engine is now Programmable Search Engine](https://programmablesearchengine.googleblog.com/2020/04/custom-search-engine-is-now_30.html).

Comment: Related [What to do with \[*search*\]? Review of tag naming practices in Web Applications SE for tags using "search"](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5144/88163)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Now there is a feature to download the site list. Here are the steps I used:

1. Go to your custom search engine
2. Click on Advanced tab under Control Panel. The url looks something like http://www.google.com/cse/panel/advanced?.....
3. Look for Download Annotations in the main pane and download in your preferred format

Comment: This answer is obsolete.

Answer (score 2):

There doesn't appear a "nice" way of doing this.  There are some instructions below, which seem like a lot of work just to get a list of sites, which are taken from [this Google Support Forum Article](http://www.google.com/support/forum/p/customsearch/thread?tid=4859ad81df0340a4&hl=en).

- Go to the control panel of one of your CSEs.  On the "Basics" page of the control panel, note your "Search engine unique ID" (a.k.a. 'CX value').  The search engine ID consists of a 21-character numeric code followed by a colon and an 11-character suffix.
- Go to the "Advanced" page of the control panel.  Note the inclusion and exclusion label names mentioned in the text that says:  "... Label sites with [...] if you want to include them ...." and "... Label sites with [...] if you want to exclude them ...."  (Note: The CSE might have more than one inclusion label name.)
- Open a separate browser window or tab.  Copy and paste the URL template shown below into your browser's location bar (URL box) and make these substitutions:
- In place of "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX", substitute the 21-character code from the first part of your CSE ID.  In place of "YYYYYYYYYYY", substitute the 11-character suffix of your CSE ID.  In place of "LABELNAME" substitute one label name.
- http://www.google.com/cse/api/XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX/annotations/YYYYYYYYYYY?label=LABELNAME&num=5000&start=0&feed=0&output=tsv
- (Use copy-and-paste to make the substitutions.  Check the result carefully to make sure that the substitutions are complete and correct, and that no extra characters or blank spaces have been added.)
- Visit the resulting URL, and you should receive the TSV-formatted annotations corresponding to the specified label for the specified CSE.

**Note:**  If you encounter problems in Excel when opening the .tsv file:  Rename the file, changing the .tsv extension to .txt, and then open in Excel.)

Comment: Yeah, I was afraid of that.

Answer (score 1):

In case you want to export 'excluded sites' from within advanced options. There doesn't look to be an official way of doing it. If you open Chrome dev tools on the network tab, and click the next page of excluded sites, you can see the XHR request that is fired.

Copy the XHR link it should look something like:

```
https://cse.google.com/cse/api/XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX/annotations/XXXXXXXXX?start=10&num=10&label=_cse_exclude_XXXXXXX
```

Change start to 0 and num to however many you have (or want to export) and it should download an XML document containing how many records you have asked for.